# Java bucles con etiquetas

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Hoy he visto este tipo de bucles que nunca que he hecho, al parecer son `bucles` con nombres. Alguien sabe como funciona esto y como se llama este tipo de bucles, mucha gracias por ayudar.

Qué imprime el programa a continuación?

```
class LoopTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int counter = 0;
        outer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            middle:
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                inner:
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                    if (k - j > 0) {
                        break middle;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: A las respuestas existentes (que son correctas), quiero dejar claro que el uso de etiquetas esta en general **muy desaconsejado** (tanto en Java como en otros lenguajes) porque hacen fácil que los programadores hagan programas muy desestructurados, en los que es difícil saber como funciona el código. Y en realidad casi nunca son necesarias: llevo veinte años programando con Java y no he usado nunca una etiqueta.

Comment: Y por si no te fuera del todo claro... te recomiendo tener a la mano tu kit contra velociraptores ( si sabes a lo que me refiero )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se denominan etiquetas, sirven para poder controlar a qué bucle deseas hacerle `break` o `continue` cuando están anidados.

```
primerFor:    
for( int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   segundoFor:
   for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
     //terminará este for
     if(arr[i][j] == 1)break;
     //terminará el for con la etiqueta segundoFor
     if(arr[i][j] == 2)break segundoFor;
     //terminará el for con la etiqueta primerFor
     if(arr[i][j] == 3)break primerFor;
   }
}
```

Puedes ver más ejemplos [aquí](https://preparandoscjp.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/control-del-flujo-bucles-ii-break-continue-etiquetas/)

Answer (score 6):

En Java se les denomina etiquetas. Se pueden usar en bucles anidados para un mejor control.

```
buclePorFuera:
do{
//hacer algo
while(condicion){
if(condicion)
   break buclePorFuera;
}
}while(condicion);
```

Answer (score 6):

Es una **etiqueta** para la instrucción `break` ( o `continue`, que es otra instrucción similar): imagina que estás buscando un elemento en un array muy largo, de 10000 elementos. El elemento que buscas está en la posición 4, por ejemplo, pero no lo sabes de antemano, así que recorres el array hasta encontrarlo:

```
for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
   if (esElQueBusco(array[i]) {
      elemento=array[i];
      break;
   }
}
```

El `break` hace que nos salgamos del bucle, evitando 9995 iteraciones más que no nos interesan. Pero ¿qué pasa si tienes bucles anidados? ¿Quieres dejar de ejecutar el interno o el externo? Pues con esa etiqueta elijes el bucle que quieres dejar de ejecutar.