# Como salir de un bucle for a mitad

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, método

Hola me gustaría saber como puedo salir de un bucle for a mitad. Me explico: 
Según mi código cuando un número se repite da igual en cual de los dos arrays esté me muestra o bien esta repetido o bien esta pero no su sitio. Lo que pasa que yo quiero que me muestre solo 1 vez por cada uno repetido del usuario no por cada repetido del que crea la maquina.Paso el código.

```
public static void comprobarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {
 boolean incorrecto=false;
    for(int i=0;i<matrizUsuario.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<matrizDefecto.length;j++) {
            if(j==i&&matrizUsuario[j]==matrizDefecto[i]){
                    System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[j]+" existe y esta en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
                break;
                }
            if(i!=j&&matrizUsuario[j]==matrizDefecto[i]) {
                System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[j]+" esta, pero no en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    if(incorrecto==false) {
        System.out.println("Ninguno de estos numeros se encuentra en la cadena");
    }
}
```

Comment: aplica una condición y dentro un break;

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238148/como-se-llama-este-tipo-de-bucles-y-como-funciona/

Comment: Si necesitas salir de un bucle for a la mitad, es que quizás lo que necesitas no es un for, sino un While o un Do While. Pero aún así, si escribes `break;` harás que se termine el for inmediatamente y no pase por el resto de condiciones. Aunque no está nada recomendado poner un break dentro de un for. Usa while mejor. (No pongas el break dentro del if como en tu ejemplo)

Answer (score 4):

La sentencia break rompe la iteración del bucle que la rodea. Para romper bucles anidados hay que andar añadiendo etiquetas así que igual es preferible que emplees una variable de condición para aprender más fácil. Te comento un poco cómo son estas dos opciones.

**Break**
Es una sentencia de control de bucles que rompe la interación.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    // lo que buscas
    if (...) {
       break; // este bucle for no sigue iterando
    }
}
```

**Variable de condición**
Otra opción sería que emplearas una variable control para saber si seguir iterando o no.

```
boolean encontrado = false;
// vamos a iterar mientras haya elementos en el array y NO hayamos encontrado lo que 
// queremos
for (int i = 0; i < array.size() && !encontrado; i++){
   // condición que buscas
    if (...) {
      encontrado = true;
    }
}
```

Creo que en tu caso con usar la variable incorrecto para controlar las iteraciones lo tenemos hecho.

```
public static void comprobarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {
 boolean incorrecto=false;
    for(int i=0;i<matrizUsuario.length && !incorrecto;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<matrizDefecto.length && !incorrecto;j++) {
            if(j==i&&matrizUsuario[j]==matrizDefecto[i]){
                    System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[j]+" existe y esta en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
                }
            if(i!=j&&matrizUsuario[j]==matrizDefecto[i]) {
                System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[j]+" esta, pero no en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
            }

        }
    }
    if(!incorrecto) {
        System.out.println("Ninguno de estos numeros se encuentra en la cadena");
    }
}
```