# Terminar o finalizar ciclo foreach java

Tags: java, bucle-for

Quiero terminar o finalizar el `for` cuando cumpla la condición y no siga el bucle:

```
for (int x : listInteger) {
    if (x == y){
     // como me salgo
    }                
}
```

Gracias,

Comment: Y también https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238591/como-salir-de-un-bucle-for-a-mitad

Answer (score 4):

Uiliza la palabra reservada   `break` tu código debería de quedar así

```
for (int x : listInteger) {
    if (x == y){
     break;
    }                
}
```

Con el `break` básicamente sales de cualquier ciclo.